# Is it possible to set a flag during sql query

Tags: sql, select, union

I'm trying to do an SQL query like that

```
(SELECT ID, Name FROM Book)
UNION
(SELECT ID, Name FROM Author)
```

and I would like to know in the final table which ids are from book and which ones from author
setting a flag or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select a static text such as

```
(SELECT ID, Name, "Book" FROM Book) UNION (SELECT ID, Name, "Author" FROM Author)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
SELECT ID, Name, 'From Book' AS FromWhome 
FROM Book
UNION
SELECT ID, Name, 'From Author'
FROM Author
```

Answer (score 0):

Select values allow columns and expressions, also you can named your new column result in this way:

```
SELECT ID, Name, 'book' as tag FROM Book
UNION 
SELECT ID, Name, 'author' as tag FROM Author
```